# SQL Server LocalDB stop command takes too long

Tags: sql-server, performance, localdb

Part of our integration process is creating clean instance of localDB and run some test on it and delete it.

Creating, starting a deleting LocalDB takes reasonable amount of time, but stopping of localDB takes much more longer.

Every command is executed as separate process. Used [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/express-localdb-instance-apis/command-line-management-tool-sqllocaldb-exe) are following:

```
SqlLocalDb stop v12.0
SqlLocalDb delete v12.0
SqlLocalDb create v12.0 12.0
SqlLocalDb start v12.0
```

Duration of commands is following.

```
SqlLocalDb command stop v12.0 took 12041 ms.
SqlLocalDb command delete v12.0 took 20 ms.
SqlLocalDb command create v12.0 12.0 took 929 ms.
SqlLocalDb command start v12.0 took 623 ms.
```

1. Why it takes so long?
2. It is possible to make it faster?

Comment: Probably because it tries to be clean about it, flush log files, detach databases, set security, all that jazz. Shutting down a SQL Server isn't a fast operation (it was never optimized to be). You could try issuing a `SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT` command on the instance itself, which should instantly kill the process. Alternatively, *don't* shut down the whole instance, just drop the database(s) involved in the process. This is much faster than stopping/starting a whole server. Unless your integration process messes with the system DBs, of course.

Comment: Whoops. I should RTFM and notice that `sqllocaldb command stop` actually *has* a `-i` flag that does exactly that: `NOWAIT`, and not only that, it even has a `-k` flag to kill the whole process without even doing *that*. `-k` should be the absolute fastest way to take it down (but *never* do this if you want to start it again later, as you're forcing the server to run recovery).

Comment: Have you looked at the SqlLocaldb hithub project, it manages instances for you for integration testing